# impedir subir archivo si ya existe usando la clase class.upload.php de verot.net

Tags: php

Este fragmento es el que se usa para hacer la accion del formulario, pero me gustaria saber como hacer para comprobar si ya existe el mismo archivo, que te salga una advertencia de que ya hay un archivo con el mismo nombre.

```
$handle = new upload($_FILES['image_field']);
if ($handle->uploaded) {
  $handle->file_new_name_body   = 'image_resized';
  $handle->image_resize         = true;
  $handle->image_x              = 100;
  $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
  $handle->process('/home/user/files/');
  if ($handle->processed) {
    echo 'image resized';
    $handle->clean();
  } else {
    echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo asi para validar si existe el archivo dentro de un directorio con php.

```
$nombreArchivoSubido= 'aqui va el nombre del archivo que subiste';
$carpeta = '/nombreCarpetaARecorrer';
//usamos scandir para ver todo el contenido del archivo
$ficheros= scandir($carpeta);
//variable que incrementaremos si hay una coincidencia
$coincidencia= 0;
$mensaje = "";
//recorremos los archivos con for y condicionamos dentro con if
for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($ficheros);$i++){
//preguntamos si es igual al nombre del archivo
 if($nombreArchivoSubido == $ficheros[$i]){
    //incrementamos la variable coincidencia
    $coincidencia++;
  }

}

//preguntamos si la variable coincidencia es mayor a 0
if($coincidencia>0){

  $mensaje = "Este archivo existe! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ "

}
return $mensaje;
```

En el código que hice arriba comente lo que hace, pero lo importante es el **scandir**,
 
**¿Qué hace scandir?**

> Bueno su funcionalidad es enumerar lo archivos ubicados dentro y lo
>   devuelve como un array.

Espero te sirva.Saludos!.

Comment: me sirvo de mucho tu codigo, pero por si alguien le sirve encontre un parametro la para funcion de class.upload y es file_overwrite = true con esto podemos saber si el archivo ya existe o no, pero tu codigo me sirvio de mucho incluso lo usare para otros modulos especificos. Saludos

Comment: denada estimado, que bueno que te sirvió igual.